# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 43 Error

Tags: python

So I've searched for other exercise 43 questions on here and none had the issue I am having.

For reference: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

After creating the game shown exactly as is (as far as I'm aware), I can not for the life of me figure out how to get it to run. This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 220, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 20, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

All of my scenes have an enter attribute right at the start, and all seem to be formatted properly as far as I can tell. The game should see that ".enter()" and go straight into printing what's underneath it in class "CentralCorridor". Anyone know how I could fix this error?

Here is a tiny snippet of the central corridor scene:

```
class CentralCorridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "bla"
        print "more bla"
```

Here is how the engine code looks like:

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As the error message tells you, `current_scene` is a **function**, not a `Scene` subclass instance; without a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't tell you why!

Comment: You definitively need to show some of your code. Maybe _your_ class `Engine` (or class `Map`) ? Could be a missing `()` but without seeing your code, this is pure speculation...

Comment: Added in my engine class. As far as I can tell it looks like the example provided in the text.

Comment: Re-read [Rule 2](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/intro.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment: missing `()` !

```
def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene  # <--- HERE !!!
```

- With the `()` the right-hand side is a function call, and the statement will affect the *result* of that call to `current_scene`.
- Without the `()`, the statement will make `current_scene` reference the *function* itself.